# creating submenu on hover and make it topmost

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery to create a submenu on hover.

here's what it looks like :

```
<div id="menucontainer">
  <ul id = "topmenu">
    <li><a onmouseover="javascript:show('div_1');">menu_1</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="javascript:show('div_2');">menu_2</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="javascript:show('div_3');">menu_3</a></li> # fine with onmouseover since code is generated from templates

  </ul>
  <div id="div_1" class="submenu">
    <ul>
      <li> submenu_1 </li>
      <li> submenu_2 </li>
      <li> submenu_3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="div_3" class="submenu">
    <ul>
      <li> submenu_1 </li>
      <li> submenu_2 </li>
      <li> submenu_3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="div_3" class="submenu">
    <ul>
      <li> submenu_1 </li>
      <li> submenu_2 </li>
      <li> submenu_3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
#topmenu {
  list-style: none;
}
#topmenu > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

<script>
function show(divid) {
  $('.submenu').css('display', 'none');
  $('#'+divid).css('display', 'block');
}
</script>
```

problem is that when `show(div)` is called and submenu div is displayed, I have another div after "menucontainer" and that div blocks clicks to displayed div. How can I solve this?

Comment: *Why* are you using jQuery for this? Unless you *need* to support IE6 there's no reason whatsoever to complicate a drop-down menu selection with jQuery or any other type of JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas I need to support IE6 and jQuery is less complicated than CSS when all menu contents is automatically generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've restructured your HTML a little to make things simpler. Also, it's better to use event listeners rather than inline function calls. Let me know if something about this won't work in your case.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dn2mv/5

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <ul id="topmenu">
        <li><a href="#">menu_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu_3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="div_1" class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li>submenu_1</li>
            <li>submenu_1</li>
            <li>submenu_1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div_2" class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li>submenu_2</li>
            <li>submenu_2</li>
            <li>submenu_2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div_3" class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li>submenu_3</li>
            <li>submenu_3</li>
            <li>submenu_3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

$('#topmenu li a').hover(function () {
    var myItem = $(this).parents('li').index() + 1;
    $('#div_' + myItem).slideDown();
}, function () {
    $('.submenu').hide();
});
```